# How to retrieve unread mails using IMAP c client feeds

Tags: imap

Is there any way to retrieve only unread mails from specific person with email address  person@gmail.com using IMAP C client Apis.
I know it can be done by using mail_search (unseen flag), but I think it would be more expensive to query every time. Please suggest a better way to do this.

If possible can you please post a sample program.

Thanks in advance.
Regards
Subbi

Answer (score 0):

search with unseen flag is the best option since any of the commands that you are going to fire will scan the entire mailbox in order to list down the unread mails. Have developed a imap server for a mailer and with my experirnce its not possible. But at clients end you can manage a map of mail states(like read forward replied..)